# Aligning Brushes to Edge with Grid (PS)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel-art, brush

I've made a custom brush in Photoshop and I'm trying to use it on a pixel grid that I've set up. However, whenever I try to use it, either with a brush or pencil (I'm relying on the pencil tool for it's non-anti-aliasing), it offsets the brush to the center of the grid points instead of aligning the brush to the grid like so:

[image: incorrect brush]

Before you dismiss this with "It's not possible to do what you're trying to do...", I have made other brushes just like this one, which deliver the desired effect, namely they **stay in the grid** instead of just painting to the center grid lines.

I don't know what setting I changed to get this brush to attach to the grid lines, instead of lock in the spaces in between the lines. Anyone know how to change this brush setting so it applies the brush correctly?

Comment: What do you have your units/grid preferences set to? And have you checked your snap settings too?

Comment: I have grid every 4 square pixels. So there is a gridline every 2 pixels, creating a block of four pixels (2x2). Behavior seems to be the same with or without snap to grid. Other snaps are turned off.

Comment: How did you manage to get the others lined up correctly?

Comment: did you try changing the brush settings? I mean the size and spacing? I would guess that the size of the brush is a multiple of 2 and the spacing is 100%

Comment: If i would have to guess then id say your brush mode was set to `Disolve`. but i dont have to guess. Alternatively a brush texture or even both.

Comment: Seems your brush simply has odd-numbered dimensions (9×9 squares) so is lining up on its centers, while an even-numbered design would center along the edges.

Comment: Oh hell... I hadn't even thought of that. You know that seems so obvious now, I can't believe I never thought about it before. Thanks. I'm going to try that and if that fixes the problem then you should write that as the answer and I'll select it. Thank you so much! I had given up on this a while ago because I just thought there was now way to do it. I'm so relieved that this question will finally have an answer!

Comment: Am I missing something? Why don't you just use 1 pixel for 1 pixel? Why scale it? If you want to add stuff in a higher resolution you could just finish your pixelart in 1:1 and then upscale it with nearest neighbor.

Comment: @Digital Brent Have you tried using Illustrator for this type of work?

Comment: @DigitalBrent did you find an answer for your question? Do you mind posting it and accepting so we can close this question?

Answer (score 1):

Nayhem's comment turned out to be the solution for me: "Seems your brush simply has odd-numbered dimensions (9×9 squares) so is lining up on its centers, while an even-numbered design would center along the edges."